# I have attempted to supply hand written shellcode, but it is being read as a string and not as bytes, what next?

Tags: security, exploit

How do I get "\x90" to be read as the byte value corresponding to the x86 NOP instruction when supplied as a field within the standard argument list in Linux? I have a buffer being stuffed all the way to 10 and then being overwritten into the next 8 bytes with the new return address, at least so I would like. Because the byte sequence being supplied is not read as a byte sequence but rather as characters, I do not know how to fix this. What next?

Comment: I am not completly understand, you received data string contains 0x90 value and you want to call NOP assembly command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can write a binary file (for example with python) and launch your program like `./exploitme < in` redirecting the stdin. You could use a oneliner with python like `python -c "print '\x90'" | ./exploitme`. Or better use pwntools